# Why is left ideal called right?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, ideals

For operations between elements of an algebraic structure:

- If $a \cdot b = c$, then $a$ is a *left* divisor of $c$;
- If $a \cdot b = 0$, then $a$ is a *left* zero divisor;
- If $a \cdot b = e$, then $a$ is a *left* inverse of $b$;
- ...

For operations between an element and an algebraic structure S:

- The map $a \cdot S$ is a *left* translation of an element $a$ (N.Bourbaki);
- If $a \cdot S$ is the identity permutation of $S$, then $a$ is a *left* identity;
- If $a \cdot S$ is an injection, then $a$ is *left* cancellable;
- ...

For operation between algebraic structures:

- In $A \oplus S$: $A$ is a *left* summand;
- In $A \times S$: $A$ is a *left* operand;
- ...

Why is a *left* ideal (in the sense above) $a \cdot S$ ($A \cdot S$ = $A$) called a *right* ideal of $S$?

This never bothered me until I started finding connections between the terms.
For example, if *left* associates are elements that generate the same *left* ideal, then $a$ and $b$ are *left* associates if and only if $a$ and $b$ are *right* divisors of each other in a ring with unity.
This sounds like there is some mechanic that switches operands, but it is merely a confusing naming convention.

Comment: Left and right are by no means used definitively: they're just used as mnemonics to remember the definitions for which they stand. For example, what you wrote as "left cancellable" is also called "right regular" in the sense it has right annihilator zero.  By the way, I have never heard "Left summand" being used as a real term. Surely it was only used as a literal verbal description of the notation, and not as a mathematical term.

Comment: @rschwieb How bad is to start calling a right ideal "left" and vice versa when explaining the properties of left and right associates (from my example)? If I am not mistaken, the notions of ideals never considered associated elements. What would be the best options for the naming in this case?

Comment: Calling a right ideal "left ideal" will confuse the hell out of everybody because it goes against the easy mnemonic naming for right ideals.  I don't think the fact that the thing you want to discuss having the adjective "left" is not a problem at all, even if it's related to right ideals.

Comment: "$a$ and $b$ generate the same left ideal iff they are right divisors of each other" is completely clear.  Also I suppose you could go this route:  "$a$ and $b$ generate the same left ideal iff they are _left multiples of each other_."   We don't have to be imprisoned by terminology you know. :)

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you.

Comment: no problemo ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One defining property of a right ideal $A\subseteq S$ is that $As\subseteq A$ for any $s\in S$. In words, $A$ is closed under *right* multiplication.

So it makes sense to call it a right ideal. That is not to say it is senseless to call it a left ideal. Some times when establishing a convention one has to choose between two (or more) options, and it's not always possible to make a perfect choice.

Comment: +1 In other words, a right ideal of $S$ is a right $S$-module.